# Why my SSDs are in /dev/hdx instead of /dev/sdx on CentOS 5.9?

Tags: centos5, ssd, sata

I have two SSDs Kingston SH103S3240G plugged on SATA ports of my Intel Server Board S3000AH.
The SSDs apear like a PATA device (hdx instead of sdx) on my CentOS 5.9.

[I'm having problems related to high iowait](https://serverfault.com/questions/521322/centos-5-extremely-slow-when-is-running-a-download). Does this have something related?

On motherboard setup the `SATA mode` are `Enhanced`.